# Copy a PNG file from the Resources to a local folder

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, resources, gdi+

I'm creating an installer for an application but I have an issue with copying my PNG file to a local folder from my Resources.

I've tried the usual stuff like `File.Copy`, `File.WriteAllBytes()` but nothing seems to work. I only get error:

> bitmap cannot be converted to Byte()

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(FileFolderOther & "\LogoReport.png") = False Then
    File.Copy(My.Resources.Logo_Reports, FileFolderOther & "\LogoReport.png", True)
End If

If System.IO.File.Exists(FileFolderOther & "\LogoReport.png") = False Then
    File.WriteAllBytes(FileFolderOther & "\LogoReport.png", My.Resources.Logo_Reports)
End If
```

I just want to copy files (PNG, TXT etc.) from `My.Resources` to a local folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`My.Resources.[SomeImage]` returns an Image object.

You can use the [Image.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save) method to save the Image to disc:

```
Dim destinationPath = Path.Combine(FileFolderOther, "LogoReport.png")
Using myLogo As Bitmap = My.Resources.Logo_Reports
    myLogo.Save("d:\testImage.png", ImageFormat.Png)
End Using
```

The `File.Exist()` check is only needed if, for some reason, you don't want to overwrite a file with same name. If the file exists, it will be overwritten without errors.

The **`Using`** statement allows to dispose of the Image created by the [ResourceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager) factory. If you need to store that Image, assign it to a Field/Property and dispose of it when the container Form/owner Class is closed/disposed.

---

You have hard-coded the Image type (`.Png`).
Maybe that's the correct, original, format of that bitmap. If you instead don't know what is the type of a Resource Image (or any other Image) and you want preserve the original format, you can derive the Codec used to create the bitmap, using the [Image.RawFormat.Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.rawformat) property and determine the correct [ImageCodecInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo) comparing the Guid with the [Codec FormatID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo.formatid) property.

I'm adding an [EncoderParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter) that set the Image quality to `100%`:

```
Using myLogo As Bitmap = My.Resources.Logo_Reports
    Dim codec As ImageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().
        FirstOrDefault(Function(enc) enc.FormatID = myLogo.RawFormat.Guid)

    ' Assunimg codec is not nothing, otherwise abort
    Dim fileName = $"LogoReport.{codec.FormatDescription.ToLower()}"
    Dim qualityParam As EncoderParameter = New EncoderParameter(ImageCodec.Quality, 100L)
    Dim codecParms As EncoderParameters = New EncoderParameters(1)
    codecParms.Param(0) = qualityParam

    Dim destinationPath = Path.Combine(FileFolderOther, fileName)
    myLogo.Save(destinationPath, codec, codecParms)
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

It is done and I've tested it correctly, but to know I have created a new folder named as "TmpFolder" inside the project folder "Debug\TmpFolder\", then try this code:

```
Private Sub BtbCopyFromResource_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtbCopyFromResource.Click
    Try
        'My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory is the function for ===> current Project path, namly to Debug Folder
        My.Resources.LogoReports.Save(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\TmpFolder\db3451.png")
        MsgBox("Done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you all brothers.
^_^

[image]